# Why my eventmachine client code doesn't work asynchronously?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, asynchronous, eventmachine, fiber

```
def index
  p "INDEX, #{Fiber.current.object_id}" # <- #1
  EventMachine.run {
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://google.com/').get :query => {'keyname' => 'value'}

    http.errback { p "Uh oh, #{Fiber.current.object_id}"; EM.stop } # <- #2
    http.callback {
      p "#{http.response_header.status}, #{Fiber.current.object_id}" # <- #3
      p "#{http.response_header}"
      p "#{http.response}"

      EventMachine.stop
    }
  }

  render text: 'test1'
end
```

In this code, I expected getting different `Fiber` id at `#1`, `#2`, `#3` line. But all fiber objects' id was same. I tried `Thread.current.object_id`, but it was same result too.
What am I misunderstaning? Is that code even executes asynchronously?

P.S I'm using `ruby 2.0` and the code is running with `rails4`

Comment: You should use em-synchrony to see your Fibers :)

Answer (score 1):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fiber.html

> Fibers are primitives for implementing light weight cooperative
>   concurrency in Ruby. Basically they are a means of creating code
>   blocks that can be paused and resumed, much like threads. The main
>   difference is that they are never preempted and that the scheduling
>   must be done by the programmer and not the VM.

Where in your code are you scheduling fibers, e.g. calling Fiber.yield or my_fiber.resume?

> current() → fiber
>   Returns the current fiber.
>   You need to require 'fiber' before using this method. If you are not
>   running in the context of a fiber this method will return the root
>   fiber.

Where in your code have you created additional fibers, e.g. Fiber.new do ...?

> Is that code even executes asynchronously?

```
require 'em-http-request'
require 'fiber'

puts Fiber.current.object_id

def index
  p "INDEX, #{Fiber.current.object_id}" # <- #1
  EventMachine.run {
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://google.com/').get :query => {'keyname' => 'value'}

    http.errback { p "#{Uh oh}, #{Fiber.current.object_id}"; EM.stop } # <- #2
    http.callback {
      p "#{http.response_header.status}, #{Fiber.current.object_id}" # <- #3
      p "#{http.response_header}"
      p "#{http.response}"

      EventMachine.stop
    }
  }

  #render text: 'test1'
end

index()

--output:--
2157346420
"INDEX, 2157346420"
"301, 2157346420"
"{\"LOCATION\"=>\"http://www.google.com/?keyname=value\", \"CONTENT_TYPE\"=>\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\", \"DATE\"=>\"Mon, 22 Jul 2013 08:44:35 GMT\", \"EXPIRES\"=>\"Wed, 21 Aug 2013 08:44:35 GMT\", \"CACHE_CONTROL\"=>\"public, max-age=2592000\", \"SERVER\"=>\"gws\", \"CONTENT_LENGTH\"=>\"233\", \"X_XSS_PROTECTION\"=>\"1; mode=block\", \"X_FRAME_OPTIONS\"=>\"SAMEORIGIN\", \"CONNECTION\"=>\"close\"}"
"<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>301 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF=\"http://www.google.com/?keyname=value\">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"
```

Nope.

And this is an error:

```
http.errback { p "#{Uh oh}"  ...
```

Comment: +1, I think the code operates Fiber is in EventMachine and em-http-request library. And your answer `Nope` is not clear yet to understand how it works. `errback` has fixed.

Comment: `I think the code operates Fiber is in EventMachine`  No.  Look at the code carefully, then look at the object_id's in the output.

Answer (score 0):

As a [search of the repository](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/search?q=Fiber&ref=cmdform) shows, `em-http` does not use fibers by default. The link, however, lists an example of how you can use fibers if you are so inclined.